# In SSIS Break points cannot be set to

Tags: ssis

In SSIS online test, I got this question.

Breakpoints cannot be set to:

```
1. Task, 
2. container, 
3. package, 
4. script task.
```

Help, please.

Comment: Hi, please see point three [the following document](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)...

Comment: cannot be set inside a task.

Comment: firstly I don't have much experience in working with MSBI, I'm just learning it. Second I have searched for an answer, but I can't come to a correct and definite conclusion. Some are telling script task but in order to debug the code in script task we need breakpoints.

Comment: Your test is outdated

Comment: Please see this link @BhupeshC        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141754.aspx

Comment: @Asha Yes, thats right. You can have a breakpoint in on any task in the control flow but not inside a data flow task.

Answer (score 0):

To score the point, select "4. Script Task" but as others have stated, that really is a poor question.

Before I begin my explanation, please note the difference between a "Script Task" and "Script Component."  The Script Task is used on the Control Flow.  The Script Component is used inside a Dataflow.  The Script Component was not able to be debugged using breakpoints in SSIS 2008.  This [changed with SSIS 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2012/01/13/script-component-debugging-in-ssis-2012.aspx).

However, the question mentions Script Task.  To my knowledge, Script Tasks have ALWAYS been able to hit breakpoints. We just need to take some steps to enable it.

1. Set the SSIS Project's "Run64BitRuntime" propery's value from its default True to False.
2. Edit your Script Task with "Edit Script" and save it again. This will help your script task code to be compiled as 32bit.

Once both your project and script task are compiled and executing in 32-bit mode, the breakpoints will be hit.  See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2010/03/17/why-the-breakpoints-that-i-set-in-my-script-task-not-script-component-in-the-data-flow-never-hits.aspx) for more information.